# Why is drush behaving strangely on this site-install run of open atrium?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to set up openatrium to run on continuous integration with Jenkins, and part of this involves building it from scratch using a drush command.

I'm having some trouble here though:

Here's the command I'm running, in debug and verbose mode:

```
drush site-install openatrium --db-url=mysql://web_dir_1:web_dir@localhost/web_dir_1 -v -d
```

Here's the output from the command. I'm setting this to run as verbosely as possible, to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.02 sec, 3.29 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.02 sec, 3.55 MB] [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.05 sec, 8.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.06 sec, 8.31 MB]                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.20 root directory at /Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir [0.07 sec, 9.36 MB]                                                                                [notice]
Found command: site-install (commandfile=core) [0.07 sec, 9.36 MB]                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initializing drush commandfile: drush_make [0.07 sec, 9.36 MB]                                                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Initializing drush commandfile: drush_make_d_o [0.07 sec, 9.37 MB]                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initializing drush commandfile: user [0.07 sec, 9.37 MB]                                                                                                                                 [bootstrap]
You are about to create a sites/default/files directory and create a sites/default/settings.php file and DROP your 'web_dir_1' database and then CREATE a new one. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
Sites directory sites/default already exists - proceeding. [1.16 sec, 9.38 MB]                                                                                                              [notice]
Calling copy(sites/default/default.settings.php, sites/default/settings.php)
Calling mkdir(sites/default/files)
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [1.17 sec, 9.4 MB]                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [1.17 sec, 9.41 MB]                                                                                                                        [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [1.18 sec, 9.41 MB]                                                                                                      [bootstrap]

Calling system(mysql --database=information_schema --host=localhost --user=root --password=  < /private/var/folders/eO/eO9NhXKBFrSOhZaCBGs2EE+++TI/-Tmp-/phplVq9zQ);
```

The stuff above sets up the empty databases, and as far as I can tell the following commands fake a web browser, stuffing the local and install profile to use, into the $_GET array:

```
Executing: php -r 'error_reporting(E_ERROR);$_GET=array("profile"=>"openatrium", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"); $_REQUEST=&$_GET;define("DRUSH_SITE_INSTALL6", TRUE);$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = NULL;$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/install.php";$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "default";$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";function _cli_cookie_print(){print(serialize(array(session_name()=>session_id())));}
register_shutdown_function("_cli_cookie_print"); include("/Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir/install.php");'
  a:1:{s:36:"SESSc21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682";s:26:"5cbv02bvq4npfbo6vds3tq3he1";}
```

This pages looks like the pages being generated for thw web ui, as if you were setting up using web browser:

```
Executing: php -r '$_GET=array("profile"=>"openatrium", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"); $_REQUEST=&$_GET;define("DRUSH_SITE_INSTALL6", TRUE);$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = NULL;$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/install.php";$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "default";$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";$_COOKIE=unserialize("a:1:{s:36:\"SESSc21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\";s:26:\"5cbv02bvq4npfbo6vds3tq3he1\";}"); $_GET["op"]="start"; include("/Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir/install.php");'
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://default/install.php?locale=en&profile=openatrium&id=1&op=do_nojs">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      <title>Installing Open Atrium | Drupal</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/defaults.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system-menus.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/maintenance.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/style.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/minnelli/minnelli.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/themes/garland/print.css?0" />
          <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/fix-ie.css" />    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="sidebar-left">

  <!-- Layout -->
    <div id="header-region" class="clear-block"></div>

      <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="container" class="clear-block">

        <div id="header">
          <div id="logo-floater">
          <h1><a href="/" title="Drupal"><img src="/themes/garland/minnelli/logo.png" alt="Drupal" id="logo" /><span>Drupal</span></a></h1>        </div>

        </div> <!-- /header -->

                <div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar">
                      <ol class="task-list"><li class="done">Choose profile</li><li class="done">Choose language</li><li class="done">Verify requirements</li><li class="done">Set up database</li><li class="active">Install profile</li><li class="">Configure site</li><li class="">Install Open Atrium modules</li><li class="">Configure Open Atrium</li><li class="">Finished</li></ol>        </div>

        <div id="center"><div id="squeeze"><div class="right-corner"><div class="left-corner">
            <h2>Installing Open Atrium</h2>                              <div class="clear-block">
              <div id="progress" class="progress"><div class="bar"><div class="filled" style="width: 0%"></div></div><div class="percentage">0%</div><div class="message">Initializing.<br/>&nbsp;</div></div>          </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div></div></div></div> <!-- /.left-corner, /.right-corner, /#squeeze, /#center -->


      </div> <!-- /container -->
    </div>
  <!-- /layout -->

    </body>
  </html>
```

Again, more loading for a web browser to see:

```
Executing: php -r '$_GET=array("profile"=>"openatrium", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"); $_REQUEST=&$_GET;define("DRUSH_SITE_INSTALL6", TRUE);$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = NULL;$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/install.php";$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "default";$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";$_COOKIE=unserialize("a:1:{s:36:\"SESSc21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\";s:26:\"5cbv02bvq4npfbo6vds3tq3he1\";}"); $_GET["op"]="do_nojs"; include("/Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir/install.php");'
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://default/install.php?locale=en&profile=openatrium&id=1&op=do_nojs">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      <title>Installing Open Atrium | Drupal</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/defaults.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system-menus.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/maintenance.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/style.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/minnelli/minnelli.css?0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/themes/garland/print.css?0" />
          <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/fix-ie.css" />    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="sidebar-left">

  <!-- Layout -->
    <div id="header-region" class="clear-block"></div>

      <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="container" class="clear-block">

        <div id="header">
          <div id="logo-floater">
          <h1><a href="/" title="Drupal"><img src="/themes/garland/minnelli/logo.png" alt="Drupal" id="logo" /><span>Drupal</span></a></h1>        </div>

        </div> <!-- /header -->

                <div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar">
                      <ol class="task-list"><li class="done">Choose profile</li><li class="done">Choose language</li><li class="done">Verify requirements</li><li class="done">Set up database</li><li class="active">Install profile</li><li class="">Configure site</li><li class="">Install Open Atrium modules</li><li class="">Configure Open Atrium</li><li class="">Finished</li></ol>        </div>

        <div id="center"><div id="squeeze"><div class="right-corner"><div class="left-corner">
            <h2>Installing Open Atrium</h2>                              <div class="clear-block">
              <div id="progress" class="progress"><div class="bar"><div class="filled" style="width: 28%"></div></div><div class="percentage">28%</div><div class="message">Remaining 33 of 46.<br/>Installed <em>Search</em> module.</div></div>          </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div></div></div></div> <!-- /.left-corner, /.right-corner, /#squeeze, /#center -->


      </div> <!-- /container -->
    </div>
  <!-- /layout -->

    </body>
  </html>
```

And now, it looks like it's finished (check for the `GET['op']="finished"`):

```
Executing: php -r '$_GET=array("profile"=>"openatrium", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"); $_REQUEST=&$_GET;define("DRUSH_SITE_INSTALL6", TRUE);$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = NULL;$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/install.php";$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "default";$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";$_COOKIE=unserialize("a:1:{s:36:\"SESSc21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\";s:26:\"5cbv02bvq4npfbo6vds3tq3he1\";}"); $_GET["op"]="finished"; include("/Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir/install.php");'
```

This final step is setting admin settings so get into the site with:

```
Executing: php -r '$_GET=array("profile"=>"openatrium", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"); $_REQUEST=&$_GET;define("DRUSH_SITE_INSTALL6", TRUE);$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = NULL;$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/install.php";$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "default";$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "127.0.0.1";$_COOKIE=unserialize("a:1:{s:36:\"SESSc21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\";s:26:\"5cbv02bvq4npfbo6vds3tq3he1\";}");
  $_POST = array (
    "site_name" => "Site-Install", 
    "site_mail" => "admin@example.com", 
    "account" => array (
      "name" => "admin",
      "mail" => "admin@example.com",
      "pass" => array (
        "pass1" => "admin",
        "pass2" => "admin"
      )
    ),
    "date_default_timezone"=>"0", 
    "clean_url"=>1,
    "form_id"=>"install_configure_form", 
    "update_status_module" => array("1"=>"1")
  );


  include("/Users/chrisadams/employer-code/perky.dev/web_dir/install.php");'
Command dispatch complete [13.75 sec, 9.43 MB]                                                                                                                                              [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   12.578     1      12578.01   

Peak memory usage was 9.56 MB [13.76 sec, 9.43 MB]
```

#### All looks good, right?

This is the screen I see at the end - the same old garland theme at we get by default (I don't yet have enough points to post images on this site)

https://community.openatrium.com/sites/community.openatrium.com/files/obvious_not_open_atrium.png

The install profile has worked, but for Garland, not OA, and none of the modules you would see in OA are there

Here's the output of `drush st`:

```
Drupal version         :  6.20                                           
 Site URI               :  http://default                                 
 Database driver        :  mysql                                          
 Database hostname      :  localhost                                      
 Database username      :  root                                           
 Database name          :  rbu_1                                          
 Database               :  Connected                                      
 Drupal bootstrap       :  Successful                                     
 Drupal user            :  Anonymous                                      
 Default theme          :  garland                                        
 Administration theme   :  garland                                        
 PHP configuration      :  /private/etc/php.ini                           
 Drush version          :  4.4                                            
 Drush configuration    :                                                 
 Drush alias files      :                                                 
 Drupal root            :  /Users/chrisadams/headshift-code/perky.dev/rbu 
 Site path              :  sites/default                                  
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files
```

When I run through these installation steps through the web browser when I call `drush st`, here's what I see:

Here's the output of `drush st`:

```
Drupal version         :  6.20                                           
 Site URI               :  http://default                                 
 Database driver        :  mysqli                                         
 Database hostname      :  localhost                                      
 Database username      :  rbu_1                                          
 Database name          :  rbu_1                                          
 Database               :  Connected                                      
 Drupal bootstrap       :  Successful                                     
 Drupal user            :  Anonymous                                      
 Default theme          :  ginkgo                                         
 Administration theme   :  ginkgo                                         
 PHP configuration      :  /private/etc/php.ini                           
 Drush version          :  4.4                                            
 Drush configuration    :                                                 
 Drush alias files      :                                                 
 Drupal root            :  /Users/chrisadams/headshift-code/perky.dev/rbu 
 Site path              :  sites/default                                  
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files
```

This uses a different database driver, and has the correct themes set, and uses a different db username, and makes me wonder if this is the issue, but I'm not quite sure what might be the cause beyond this here.

The only changes I made here, in this were using a different database user, `rbu_1`, and a different password `rbu` instead of `root` and `''` for the password (I know it's bad practice, to use root like this - I switched to it when I was trying to eliminate permissions problems when debugging this issue earlier).

Any idea Open Atrium would behave differently under these two conditions?

I can do this process through the web browser, and this installs fine, but this won't be enough to setup CI for a project I'm working on.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, and I'd really appreciate some pointers. Any ideas, other than using `curl` and `wget` or `mechanize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

site-install can sort of handle complex install profiles in Drupal 7 (especially the upcoming Drush5) but such profiles are virtually impossible to support in Drupal 6. The Drupal 6 installer is just not built for non-web use. Sorry.